# Import XML file into Access and create grandparent/parent/child relationships

Tags: xml, ms-access, xslt, import

Upfront, I'm comfortable in Access and I get the general concept of XML, but I'm a complete newbie to XSLT, so please forgive my post if my explanation/terminology is poorly expressed.

I have an XML source file that I have to import into an Access database and link all `grandparent/parent/child/child/...` relationships for reporting purposes. I have read up on similar posts here (much appreciation for all previous efforts posted) and pieced together an XSLT file to create links between all of the tables that are created (*School* links to *Student* using the [unique] *SchoolNumber* field, *Student* links various of it's children using [unique] *SID* field).

However, I'm stumped as to how to get the Name node data to properly align in their respective tables.  In the XML file, the Name attribute is used for both the Student node and Guardian node, and as such it creates one Name table and puts both the Student and Guardian Name fields together in one Name table.  The Name table should only contain the *Student* names (*First, Middle, Last*) and the Guardian table should have the 
Guardian names (*First, Last*) along with the other *Guardian* fields (*Relationship, Phone, [PhoneType*).

Also, in the XML, the Guardian Phone attribute contains a nested element `type="HOME"` which should be contained in the resulting Guardian table.  The source XML (which I have no control over this) is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<ns1:SchoolUpload xmlns:ns1="http://ontario.ca">
    <ns1:School>
        <ns1:SchoolNumber>123456789</ns1:SchoolNumber>
        <ns1:Students>
            <ns1:Student>
                <ns1:SID>10101010</ns1:SID>
                <ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:First>Student1</ns1:First> 
                    <ns1:Middle>Middle</ns1:Middle>
                    <ns1:Last>Surname</ns1:Last>
                </ns1:Name>
                <ns1:AliasName>
                    <ns1:First>Red</ns1:First>
                    <ns1:Last>Blue</ns1:Last>
                </ns1:AliasName/>
                <ns1:Gender>M</ns1:Gender>
                <ns1:BirthDate>1991-10-29</ns1:BirthDate>
                <ns1:Language>en</ns1:Language>
                <ns1:Guardian>
                    <ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:First>Primary</ns1:First>
                        <ns1:Last>Guardian</ns1:Last>
                    </ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Relationship>MOTHER</ns1:Relationship>
                    <ns1:Phone type="HOME">111-111-1111</ns1:Phone>
                </ns1:Guardian>
                <ns1:Guardian>
                    <ns1:Name>
                        <ns1:First>Secondary</ns1:First>
                        <ns1:Last>Guardian</ns1:Last>
                    </ns1:Name>
                    <ns1:Relationship>FATHER</ns1:Relationship>
                    <ns1:Phone type="HOME">222-222-2222</ns1:Phone>
                </ns1:Guardian>
                <ns1:Address>
                    <ns1:StreetAddress>15 Main Street</ns1:StreetAddress>
                    <ns1:City>Guelph</ns1:City>
                    <ns1:Province>ON</ns1:Province>
                    <ns1:PostalCode>N5N5N5</ns1:PostalCode>
                </ns1:Address>
                <ns1:Phone type="HOME">333-333-3333</ns1:Phone>
            </ns1:Student>
        </ns1:Students>
    </ns1:School>
</ns1:SchoolUpload>
```

The XSLT file I've pieced together is as follows:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:ns1="http://ontario.ca"  exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="ns1:Student">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:School/ns1:SchoolNumber"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:Student/ns1:Name">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:Student/ns1:SID"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:AliasName|ns1:Guardian|ns1:Address">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:Student/ns1:SID"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Importing the XML into Access using the XSLT file results in Access creating 6 tables (*School, Student, Name, Guardian, Address, AliasName*), all of which can be linked. However, I have no idea how to achieve the end result I'm trying to achieve. In advance, I very much appreciate any feedback that can be offered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider flattening the nested *Name* and *AliasName* nodes to render them direct children to *Student* and *Guardian*. You can do so by a template of just `<xsl:apply-templates>` with no `<xsl:copy>`. And because they share the same element names, two different templates are used where *AliasName's* new children has parent *Alias* concatenated to element name for *AliasNameFirst* and *AliasNameLast*.

And since MS Access' XML methods are element-centric and ignores attributes, consider migrating the attribute to an element. And because *@type* shows up more than once, use a `xsl:call-template` to avoid repetition. With below adjusted XSLT, only four tables should import: *School, Student, Guardian, and Address.*

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0"
                xmlns:ns1="http://ontario.ca"  exclude-result-prefixes="ns1">
<xsl:output version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>  

 <xsl:template match="ns1:Student">
    <xsl:copy>      
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:School/ns1:SchoolNumber"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>      
      <xsl:call-template name="phonetype"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:Name">
    <xsl:apply-templates/>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:AliasName">
    <xsl:variable select="local-name()" name="parent_name"/>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:element name="ns1:{concat($parent_name, local-name())}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="ns1:Guardian|ns1:Address">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:copy-of select="ancestor::ns1:Student/ns1:SID"/>
      <xsl:apply-templates/>      
      <xsl:call-template name="phonetype"/>      
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="phonetype">
    <xsl:if test="ns1:Phone/@type">
      <ns1:Phonetype><xsl:value-of select="ns1:Phone/@type"/></ns1:Phonetype>
    </xsl:if>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Hi Parfait.  First off, thanks for your time and feedback (much appreciated).  I get what you did with the "phonetype" method/call to convert/add that attribute to the Student and Guardian nodes (very cool). I noticed that 'flattening' out the Name and AliasName fields had the effect of overwriting the values of Student.First and Student.Last attributes  with the Alias.First and Alias.Last (respectively).  The Student.Middle value is unaffected (I assume) because there is no Guardian.Middle attribute.  TBC...

Comment: I 'unflattened' the AliasName node and copied the Student.SID value to AliasName node, which creates an AliasName table, with a linkage to the Student table by the SID attribute.  This is a workable solution, however, I am curious to know if there is a way to flatten the AliasName field (as per your solution) and rename its First and Last sub-attributes to something else, e.g., AliasFirst and AliasLast?  The end result being that the Student table would contain First, Middle, Last, AliasFirst and AliasLast fields.

Comment: See updated XSLT script. It hadn't occurred to me that *Name* and *AliasName* share same child names.

Comment: Honestly, I learned by doing! Best tutorial for me was diving into a problem and using StackOverflow posts with issues. For VBA (all MS Office apps) read into the [MSXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms763742(v=vs.85).aspx) library for all XML handling. Tabular data like databases/spreadsheets are two-dimensions (row by col), only one format type of XML which can have various nesting. XSLT helps in migration.

Comment: And by the way do keep this up for future readers. In fact, if answer helped please click tick mark to side to accept answer and confirm resolution.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion; I wasn't going to delete the entire post, only my comment regarding recommendations.  Thanks for the heads up about the check box (I had previously selected the up arrow but didn't notice the check could also be selected).  Thanks again for your time and efforts.  Best regards, Dave.

Comment: Sorry for the ongoing thread, I tried to select add to chat, but it's telling me I don't have enough history to access that function. Anyway, looking at the end result and having thought on it, I've flattened out the Address table (included in the Student table) and I'm going to attempt to flatten the Guardian table as well.  If I am able to do that, should I modify my original post and include what that XSLT end up looking like?

Comment: Sure you can edit your orginal post with final XSLT. But why flatten *Guardian*? Keep it as its own table with one-to-many relationship with *Student* since there are two records to one student. Recall [normalization](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization) of relational databases.

Comment: Hi Parfait. I get what you're saying about normalization, however, I ultimately have to export the database back out to the original XML file format and figure that will be easier to do if all of the Student data is flat. In a nutshell, I have to: 1. Import XML into database. 2. Run a series of queries to 'scrub' the data (e.g., convert all Province values to upper case, remove a space character  from the PostalCode  values and format phone numbers to include a hyphen character 999-999-9999). 3. Remove duplicate Students (if any). 4. Export database contents back out to XML format.

Comment: You can do all that in XSLT without MS Access import/export and retaining original structure. Plus Access' [ExportXML](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193212.aspx) allows multiple tables exported in single XML, nested per relationships. See *AdditionalData* argument.